# Android, XAMARIN: Add A Single LinearLayout Header To RecyclerView's Top (Clickable)

Tags: android, xamarin, android-linearlayout, android-recyclerview

I've been looking everywhere, unable to find anything.
I managed to put up my recyclerview just right, the only thing missing is a header. In my listview I had previously, I just designed the first element to be my header. It was a linearlayout with some textviews and some images as clickable buttons inside. As for the RecyclerView I wasn't able to do that just yet. Can anyone here help me with this?

These are my 3 (working) classes for my recycler view:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private List<DataForProfile> lstData = new List<DataForProfile>();
    private Context ctx;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataForProfile> lstData, Context ctx)
    {
        this.lstData = lstData;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    } 


    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

        RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;

        viewHolder.txtTitle.Text = (lstData[position].description);
        viewHolder.imageView.SetImageBitmap((lstData[position].img));


    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
        View itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecView_Profile, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView, ctx);
    }

    //Get Number Of Items
    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get
        {
            return lstData.Count;
        }
    }

}




public class DataForProfile
{
    public int imageId { get; set; }
    public Bitmap img { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

}

class RecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView imageView { get; set; }
    public TextView txtTitle { get; set; }
    public TextView txtDescription { get; set; }
    public TextView txtDate { get; set; }
    public TextView txtLikeCountBlue { get; set; }
    public TextView txtLikeCountGreen { get; set; }
    public TextView txtComments { get; set; }
    private Typeface font;
    private Context ctx;


    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView, Context ctx) : base(itemView)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        txtTitle = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.RecView_Profile_TaskName);
        imageView = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        txtDescription = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.RecView_Profile_Description);
        txtDate = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.RecView_Profile_Date);
        txtLikeCountBlue = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_recview_profile_blue);
        txtLikeCountGreen = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_recview_profile_green);
        txtComments = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_recview_profile_comments);

        font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(ctx.Assets, "CourierNew.ttf");

        txtTitle.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
        txtDescription.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtDate.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtLikeCountBlue.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtLikeCountGreen.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtComments.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);

    }
}
```

Any help at all would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after doing some overrides - here is the working piece of code in order to do that:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private List<DataForProfile> lstData = new List<DataForProfile>();
    private Context ctx;
    private static int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static int TYPE_ITEM = 2;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataForProfile> lstData, Context ctx)
    {
        this.lstData = lstData;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    } 

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

        //Check oif Header orData
        if (holder.GetType() == typeof(HeaderViewHolder)) 
        {
            HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = holder as HeaderViewHolder;
            headerHolder.headerTitle.Text = "hall0";

            headerHolder.headerTitle.Click += delegate
            {
                Toast.MakeText(ctx, "Header!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            };

            headerHolder.headerImageView.Click += delegate
            {
                Toast.MakeText(ctx, "image!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            };
        }             
        else if (holder.GetType() == typeof(RecyclerViewHolder)) 
        {
             RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
             viewHolder.txtTitle.Text = (lstData[position-1].description); // - 1 because of the header
             viewHolder.imageView.SetImageBitmap((lstData[position-1].img));

        }

    }

    // What layout to be inflated?
    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {

        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM)
        {
            // Data
             LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
             View itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecView_Profile, parent, false);
             return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView, ctx);
        }
        else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER)
        {
            //Inflating header view
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
            View itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.testheader, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(itemView, ctx);
        }
        else return null;
    }

    // Get Number Of Items
    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get
        {
            return lstData.Count + 1; // +1 due to the header
        }
    }

    // Custom Override to decided whether its the header or the data
    public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if (position == 0)
        {
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        }
        else if (position == lstData.Count() + 1) //+1 wegen des Headers
        {
            return TYPE_ITEM;;
        }
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

}

// class for header
public class HeaderViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView headerTitle;
    public ImageView headerImageView;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView, Context ctx) : base(itemView)
    {
        headerTitle = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.testheadertitle);
        headerImageView = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.testheaderbutton);
    }
}

// xml
class RecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView imageView { get; set; }
    public TextView txtTitle { get; set; }
    public TextView txtDescription { get; set; }
    public TextView txtDate { get; set; }
    public TextView txtLikeCountBlue { get; set; }
    public TextView txtLikeCountGreen { get; set; }
    public TextView txtComments { get; set; }
    private Typeface font;
    private Context ctx;


    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView, Context ctx) : base(itemView)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        txtTitle = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.RecView_Profile_TaskName);
        imageView = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        txtDescription = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.RecView_Profile_Description);
        txtDate = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.RecView_Profile_Date);
        txtLikeCountBlue = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_recview_profile_blue);
        txtLikeCountGreen = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_recview_profile_green);
        txtComments = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_recview_profile_comments);

        font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(ctx.Assets, "CourierNew.ttf");

        txtTitle.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
        txtDescription.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtDate.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtLikeCountBlue.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtLikeCountGreen.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtComments.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);

    }
}


public class DataForProfile
{
    public int imageId { get; set; }
    public Bitmap img { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

}
```

}